# Как внедрить функцию javascript в свой браузер, что б она мониторила определённые параметры с загружаемого сайта? (не парсер)

Tags: javascript, c#, watch

Есть загружаемый сайт- отрисовывается таблица и она ежесекундно может изменяться.
Мне нужно получить значение данных таблицы.
Я хочу через встроенный браузер на С# получать значения данных. То-есть инжектить javascript и что б он сливал данные в основную программу.
По отдельности как инжектить свой javascript я понял, но как прицепить watch на элементы таблицы(я знаю, в каких элементах и классах будут сидеть нужные данные) и что б как только там изменится значение- тут же уведомить основную программу?
То-есть нужен не парсер- данные меняются ежесекундно.
Кто-то подобное делал?
Спасибо

Comment: [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)?

Comment: @vp_arth а как ему сказать, что б он постучал наверх в программу на c#?

Comment: Насколько я помню там было что-то вроде `window.external`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если не используется Mono(не приходилось ковырять), то в штатном webbrowser имеется свойство [objectforscripting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.objectforscripting(v=vs.110).aspx). Можно вызывать в javascript-е методы из C# (через window.external).

watch, вроде как, только с Gecko работал, для штатного наверное лучше onpropertychange.

Как-то так, если правильно Вас понял...

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComVisibleAttribute(true)]
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            webBrowser1.ObjectForScripting = this;
            webBrowser1.DocumentText =
            @"<html><head></head><body> 
               <table id='tbl'> 
                  <tr><td>qwerty</td><td>qwerty</td></tr>  
                  <tr><td>1</td><td onpropertychange='window.external.viewData(this.innerHTML)'>0</td></tr>
               </table>

              <script>
              function fn(){
                var td_ = document.getElementById('tbl').getElementsByTagName('td');
                td_[3].innerHTML = Math.random();
               } 
              setInterval(fn, 1000);
              </script>

              </body></html>"; 
        }

        public void viewData(string data)
        {
            richTextBox1.AppendText(data + "\r\n");
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы движок JS передавал данные в ваш браузер, нужно написать для него API и внедрить его интерфейс в окружение движка. Это самый логичный способ.

Нужно обозревать ежесекундно? setTimeout и отгрузка изменений в глобальный обьект, асинхронные функции, возвращающие в ваш браузер промис с изменениями, наконец, вызов вашего js-кода каждую секунду и возвращение результата через API.

Comment: звучит логично и красиво....но вот только как это сделать?))))